# How do you check a key in Couchbase without updating the expiration?

Tags: .net, couchbase

I want to check a key in couchbase but I don't want to update the expiration. How's that done?

I am using the .Net SDK 1.2.9

Comment: If it's just for Key existance, will not `KeyExists` work? https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-net-client/blob/master/src/Couchbase/CouchbaseClient.cs#L744

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to update the expiration time, you use get and touch operation :

```
var bearWithUpdateExpiration = client.Get("beer", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5));
```

for not updating the expiration, you use simply get operation:

```
var beer = client.Get<Beer>("beer");
```

Comment: So..the GET with no expiration will not perform a touch? Thanks let me give it a try.